# How to Predict a Trend in MATLAB with irregular sampling time?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm using MATLAB to predict a trend with a machine learning approach.

My data file is an .xlsx file containing a timeline in one column (various sampling timestamps, i.e. numbers that represents seconds), and in the other columns I have some integers representing my trend.

My .xlsx file is pretty much like this:

```
0,0100     |     0
0,0110     |     1
0,0135     |     5
```

And so on.

I used "|" to distinguish between columns. The sampling time is not regular.

Given 10 values of the trend taken from 10 consecutive timestamps, I'd like to predict the 11th value at a given timestamp. For example, if the 9th value is at 34,010 and the 10th value is at 34,568s I'd like to know the value at 37,431s.

How can I do it?

I've found this link: [Time Series Forecasting Using Deep Learning](https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/time-series-forecasting-using-deep-learning.html), but there the sampling time is regular.

Should I interpolate my trend values and re-sample them with a constant sampling time?

Comment: How many data points do you have in total? Ten seems like an awfully small amount of data to be using deep learning. Are you sure simpler techniques like linear regression will not work for your data?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually my .xlsx file can contain up to millions of data, but, given a certain timestamp, the prediction I have to do needs only a small amount of data before the said timestamp. I said "given 10 values" to give an idea of the task, but that number will be higher. Also, I said I have one .xlsx file, but actually I have several files, each with its own trend and timestamps. And the trends can be non-linear.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. In that case, I agree on using interpolation to handle the irregular sampling time. The method of interpolation would depend on the data itself; but I think linear interpolation should work in most cases. Once you have regularly sampled data, you should be able to use whatever methods for forecasting now, including the one you've linked.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would distinguish the forecasting problem from the data sampling time problem. You are dealing substantially with missing data.

1. **Forecasting problem**: You may use any machine learning technique just ignoring missing data. If you are not familiar with machine learning, I would suggest you to use LASSO (least absolute shrinkage and selection operator), which has been demonstrated to have predicting power (see "Sparse Signals in the Cross-Section of Returns" by ALEX CHINCO, ADAM D. CLARK-JOSEPH, and MAO YE).
2. **Missing imputation problem**: In the first place you should consider the reason why you have missing data. Sometime it makes no sense to impute values because the information that the value is missing is itself important and should not be overridden. Otherwise you have multiple options, other than linear interpolation, to estimate the missing values. For example check the MATLAB function `fillmissing`.